# delete button is not working if i use joins in php

Tags: php, mysql

i have one group..so in that group i can assign courses and i can assign group to the user..
so if i delete the group the users which is assigned to the group also deleted..
so for this i made update join query..so what happened is if no users are assigned to the group...its not updating the record..

here is my update query

```
  <?php 
   require('../config.php');
   if(!isset($_SESSION['can_access']) || $_SESSION['can_access'] !== true ) 
    header('Location: login.php'); 
   global $DB,$USER; 
   //$id=$USER->id; 
  $deleted_on = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
  echo $id = $_GET['id'];
   $DB->execute("UPDATE mdl_user u, mdl_moog_groups g
     SET u.trackforums = '0', g.deletestatus =  '0'
   WHERE g.id ='$id'
    AND u.secret IN ( SELECT random_no FROM mdl_accesscode ac WHERE 
 ac.group_id = '$id'");
 header("Location:groups.php"); 
 ?>
```

i dint find the solution..

can anyone help me ..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can use `JOIN`s in the `UPDATE` clause, so try something like this:

```
UPDATE mdl_user u, mdl_moog_groups g
SET u.trackforums = '0', g.deletestatus =  '0'
WHERE g.id ='$id'
  AND u.secret IN ( SELECT random_no FROM mdl_accesscode ac WHERE ac.group_id = '$id' )
```